# How to use DotNetOpenAuth to log into Google, and get user profile

Tags: dotnetopenauth, gdata

I just want to login with google and want access logged in user's general profile like photo, email address and name, to display on my site.  Is it possible with DotNetOpenAuth?

Comment: yes it's possible, but PLEASE do not post the user's e-mail address on your site (especially not as part of their public profile).

Comment: Where can I find example.  I have downloaded the sample code from dotnetopenauth.  But example make a request to get contacts.  Couldn't find example where it makes only login request.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725532/dotnetopenauth-and-google-openid-implementation also http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/3844/

Comment: How can I get user profile from google

Comment: See this link for how to retrieve the user profile from google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365572/how-do-i-retrieve-google-profile-with-dotnetopenauth

Comment: None of the link above show how to get user's profile.  I am tired of googling, not getting what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's trivially easy.  Use OpenID to "just login", instead of OAuth.  Take a look at the OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms or OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc samples for how to log a user in.  Since you're only interested in logging the user in with Google, rather than displaying an input box you can just have a "Login with Google" button that calls `OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequest("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id")` to initiate a Google login.

As @Lirik pointed out in a comment, you can use AX to [retrieve user profile info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365572/how-do-i-retrieve-google-profile-with-dotnetopenauth).  However I don't *think* that will get you the user photo.  If Google even makes that available (big if) you may have to use OAuth for that.  And I would recommend in that case that you use the "OpenID+OAuth" extension for that, which I believe leads you to the "Google Contacts" sample you have already seen.  To change that to retrieve a user photo however, you'd need to review Google's own GData API documentation to see how to retrieve a user photo (if you can).

Comment: Google just released Google+.  How would it possible to access the user's profile.  I mean how can it possible to ask user to login with google profile.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at.  These instructions will get a user to login using their Google account.  What has Google+ to do with it?  Is it the login, or their data beyond logging them in that you are after?

Comment: Data, I am wondering if Google+ profile can be accessed with user image.

Comment: I think that I would prefer using Gravatar to get a profile picture when using a login scheme such as this, but of course that is just a personal opinion. :)